# How do I make d = function(x,y)

Tags: algorithms

I am using the algorithm package and read it knowing there is `\function` to use. I want to make my output look like:

> Function d = dotproduct(x,y).

How can I accomplish this?

And this is what I have so far

```
\Function {par-dot-prod}{x,y}
```

Package used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%for the pseudo code 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

....
and partial code

\begin{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{2.a)}

\caption{Parallel Dot Product}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\Function {par-dot-prod}{x,y}   \Comment{This is a test}

    \State System Initialization
    \State Read the value 
    \If{$condition = True$}
        \State Do this
        \If{$Condition \geq 1$}
        \State Do that
        \ElsIf{$Condition \neq 5$}
        \State Do another
        \State Do that as well
        \Else
        \State Do otherwise
        \EndIf
    \EndIf

    \While{$something \not= 0$}  \Comment{put some comments here}
        \State $var1 \leftarrow var2$  \Comment{another comment}
        \State $var3 \leftarrow var4$
    \EndWhile  \label{roy's loop}
\EndFunction   

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
}
```

Comment: Oh.My bad. I absolutely will. But it is way too big and it is a file I wrote for a homework, I can not share it. 
But here are the packages I used

Comment: Can you write a minimal example that reproduces your problem and wouldn’t violate your course policies? Also, please format code samples by indenting them four spaces. (You can select them and hit the `{}` button.)

Comment: Sorry, I am really bad at formatting, this is the best I can do.

Comment: Can any of you answer this question? If not I will delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure this out, So I will tell all of you guys who may have or want to solve this problem when you are doing your homework and want to format this way.

This is what you have to do:

Put this anywhere in your document.

```
\algrenewcommand\textproc{}
```